# Is there any way to add multiple nodes ip while adding resource into apche tomcat context.xml file for cassandra?

Tags: cassandra, datasource, tomcat8, cassandra-2.0

Since CassandraDataSource takes only one host (node ip) at a time.
If that is down, it won't connect to rest of nodes in cluster, which are available.

I also tried:

```
Cluster.Builder clusterBuilder = Cluster.builder().addContactPoints("10.xx.xx.245","10.xx.xx.143").withPort(9042).withRetryPolicy(DowngradingConsistencyRetryPolicy.INSTANCE).withReconnectionPolicy(new ConstantReconnectionPolicy(100L).withPoolingOptions(poolingOptions).withLoadBalancingPolicy(new TokenAwarePolicy(new DCAwareRoundRobinPolicy()));  
        Cluster cluster = clusterBuilder.build();
        Session session=cluster.connect("tp");
```

This code is giving session object. Not finding way to create data source containing multiple node IP. So that it can automatically connect to another node in cluster if previously connected node is down.

context.xml file DS definition is as follows:

```
<Resource name="jdbc/cassandra" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
        maxActive="100" maxIdle="30" maxWait="100" driverClassName="org.apache.cassandra.cql.jdbc.CassandraDriver"
        url="jdbc:cassandra://nodeIP:9160/keyspace" username="cassandra"
        password="cassandra" />
```

Comment: The Cassandra JDBC driver does not support connecting to multiple Cassandra nodes.

https://docops.ca.com/ca-live-api-creator/4-0/en/creating-apis/database-connectivity/apache-cassandra-data-source#ApacheCassandraDataSource-limits

Comment: So if runtime that node goes down, what to do?Since only one node url we are able to specify.

Comment: Could you share you ds definition in context.xml file?

Comment: @Horia added DS context.xml code

Comment: Have you tried specifying multiple hosts in the following format? host01--host02--host03. Something like url="jdbc:cassandra://host01--host02--host03:9160/keyspace"